# How do I ensure that some script I am running will end after a certain amount of time?

Tags: c

How do I ensure that some script I am running will end after a certain amount of time

just a random question. Its not a specific prblem i was facing. i just asked out of curiosity. So its just a random question which  came to my mind

Comment: Are you talking about [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)? If yes, then as per the link, *"The halting problem is undecidable, meaning that no general algorithm exists that solves the halting problem for all possible program–input pairs."*

Comment: You write "script", but the question is tagged "c", and C programs are not usually called scripts, so what is it? Do you mean that you want the program to *finish* in the allotted time, i.e, you want a guaranteed upper bound on some execution time, or are you happy to unceremoniously terminate a half-way run that is taking too much time? In the latter case, it rather depends on the operating system (well, I suppose one can always plug in the power cord though a timer...) so which operating system are you on?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the link describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Your questions will be much less likely to be downvoted or closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the timeout command. This command is used to timeout your script after a certain amount of time. For example if you want to terminate a script after 5 seconds, you can write

```
timeout 5 ./script.sh
```

For 5 minutes delay you can write

```
timeout 5m ./script.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways.

Timeout command: (timeout command that allows you to run a command for a specified duration.)

timeout 10s your_script.sh

Signals: (You can use signals to interrupt your script after a certain duration.)

```
import signal
import time
import sys

def timeout_handler(signum, frame):
    print("Timeout exceeded. Exiting.")
    sys.exit(1)

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, timeout_handler)
signal.alarm(10)  # Set the timeout to 10 seconds

try:
    # Your script logic here
finally:
    signal.alarm(0)  # Reset the alarm
```

---

Built-in Timers: (You can build a timer into your script.)

```
import time

start_time = time.time()

# Your script logic here

elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
if elapsed_time > 10:  # 10 seconds
    print("Time limit exceeded. Exiting.")
    exit()
```

Comment: The question is tagged "C" not Python.